# Netbeans, annotation processor run on save

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, annotation-processing

I wrote an annotation processor which generate some metadata of an annotated class, 
I would like that whenever I change the annotated class and then save the changes - netbeans will run my annotation processor to fix the metadata. 
for some reason this does not work.

I added the annotation processor jar to the "compile" path and to the "processor" path in netbeans, I than enable the "annotation processing" and "enable annotation processing in editor".

The metadata get generated only once.
one workaround that I found is to disable "compile on save" and than when I try to run the program then the metadata will get generated - but I have a relatively large project and it make running the application relatively slow (1 minute of compiling before each run... )

in eclipse the annotation processor work as expected (generate the metadata on every save)
is there a way to achieve it in netbeans?